# The word "value" in moral and social values

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

The meaning of the word [value](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/value) in the third sense says:

> That which is valued or highly esteemed, such as one's morals, morality, or belief system.

Does the word **value** in **moral values** relates to this particular sense?

Do **moral values** mean *things that one values in matters of what is right and what is wrong?*

What about values such as, **social values, political values, etc.?**

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence the noun "value" means "principles or standards of behaviour; one's judgement of what is important in life. Therefore "moral value" means "moral principles, moral standards", what morally one can do and cannot do.

Social values are a societies principles or the standards of behaviour.

Political values are not any different. They are the philosophy of politics, the standards of behaviour of politicians.